# removing form from c# code?

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle

I'm extremely new to C# and programming anything except for SQL. I've gotten the below code to happen on a Form and on a button click. If I wanted to just make this run on open, how would I do that? I'm very new to C# as you can tell (just started today learning it but its pretty exciting!)

```
        using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using Oracle.DataAccess.Client; // ODP.NET Oracle managed provider
    using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;

    namespace OraTrigger
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string oradb = "Data Source=OMP1;User Id=user;Password=pass;";

                OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb); // C#

        conn.Open();

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT cast(Count(*) as varchar(20)) as trig FROM ZDMSN.TRIGGER_TEST";
        //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();

        int cnt;
        if (int.TryParse(dr.GetString(0), out cnt))
        {
            if (cnt > 0)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\testfile.bat");                    
            }
        }
        cmd.CommandText = "TRUNCATE TABLE ZDMSN.TRIGGER_TEST";
        conn.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean 'run on open'?

Comment: Does it need to be in a Forms window? You could easily do this with a command line project.

Comment: no, I just did it in the form windows because online example started with those. I want to schedule this with windows task scheduler to run every 30min...would command line project be ideal for this?

Comment: Yes - I'd recommend just creating a new C# command line project, and then copying the code above to it. You won't need all of the `using` packages; probably `System.Drawing` and `System.Windows.Forms` and `System.Threading.Tasks` can go. Try removing those, one at a time, followed by a build. If you get a build error just put back the `using` you just removed. Or you can leave them there - I'm pretty sure they're harmless (except for maybe being misleading).

Comment: Just copy the code in the `button1_Click` method when you create your command line / console project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to run your code as a scheduled task then a command line application is more suitable.

Just create a new project and select `Console Application`.
Then move all of your button click code inside the `Main` method written for you by the Visual Studio IDE.

Rembember to set the references to the Oracle ODP.NET library and import the relevant using statements

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client; // ODP.NET Oracle managed provider
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string oradb = "Data Source=OMP1;User Id=user;Password=pass;";
            using(OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb))
            using(OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT Count(*) as trig FROM ZDMSN.TRIGGER_TEST", conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                int cnt = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (cnt > 0)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\testfile.bat");
                    cmd.CommandText = "TRUNCATE TABLE ZDMSN.TRIGGER_TEST";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also revised your code to get a single value from the database. For this case is enough to use the Command.ExecuteScalar method that returns the first column of the first row obtained from your sql command text. Because the count(*) should Always return a single row you could easily cast the return value of ExecuteScalar to your record count variable.

**EDIT** I have added the logic to TRUNCATE the table involved. Please pay attention that you should use the code provided here. Your code will probably fail because you have an open DataReader and when a DataReader is open you cannot execute other commands (This is true for SqlServer without Multiple Active Result Sets enabled, I really don't know if this rules applies also  to the Oracle NET Provider)

Comment: BINGO! one thing though...by truncate table at the end doesn't seem to work...I can run the c# fine with no errors but it doesn't truncate...I updated the above code with the truncate statement

Comment: Yes, you don't run the second commandtext. You need to call `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` after setting the command

Comment: so does it look like this? cmd.ExecuteNonQuery = "TRUNCATE TABLE ZDMSN.TRIGGER_TEST"  ?

Comment: One more thing...I'm getting a InvalidCastException at int cnt = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();    hmmmmmm....I really need to pick this stuff up

Comment: Well COUNT(*) should return a integer, but then you have all that stuff of conversion before, probably there is something in the Oracle provider. Need to check.

Comment: Well I am not sure if COUNT(*) returns an integer anymore. Try using a variable of type `double`. E.g `double cnt = (double)cmd.ExecuteScalar();` or use an `object result = (double)cmd.ExecuteScalar();`, set a breakpoint on the line and check the datatype of the object returned

Comment: hmmm...I tried casting the COUNT(*) as INT and as varchar (just in case) but both still give the same error...

Comment: ok...I got the IF statement to work with the original way, not sure why it didn't work your proposed method (looked more efficient). Both statements did seem to execute after another with the oracledatareader as well.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to `Shown` or `Load` event of form and move your code to that event handler.

- [Form.Shown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx) Occurs whenever the form is first displayed.
- [Form.Load Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx) Occurs before a form is displayed for the first time.

Also I suggest to extract your code to some Data Access related class, or at least to separate method. And call that method from event handler.